# Acess two different lists with the same type of objects in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

If I can explain my problem, these are two methods, a test method and its target:

#### Test method

```
[Fact]
public async Task Create_Post_Valid_Id_Valid_Name()
{
#region Arrange
    var model = new FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel{Id = 10, Name = "Schedule"};
    var schedules = new List<Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel>()
    {new Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel{Id = 11, Name = "AnotherSchedule"}};
    var refreshedSchedules = new List<Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel>()
    {new Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel{Id = 10, Name = "Schedule"}};
    _shippingApiClient.Setup(x => x.GetAllFixedSchedules(CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult((IList<Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel>)schedules));
    _shippingApiClient.Setup(x => x.CreateFixedSchedule(It.Is<FixedShippingScheduleEditModel>(s => s.Name == "Schedule"), CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
    _shippingApiClient.Setup(x => x.GetAllFixedSchedules(CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult((IList<Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel>)refreshedSchedules));
    _localizationService.Setup(x => x.GetResource("Bizay.Logistic.Admin.Schedules.Notification.Create.Error")).Returns("Success");
    _notificationService.Setup(x => x.SuccessNotification("Success", true));
#endregion
#region Act
    var result = await _scheduleController.Create(model, true, CancellationToken.None);
#endregion
#region Assert
    result.Should().BeOfType<ViewResult>();
    ((ViewResult)result).Model.Should().BeOfType<FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel>();
    ((FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel)((ViewResult)result).Model).Name.Should().Be("AnotherSchedule");
    ((FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel)((ViewResult)result).Model).Id.Should().Be(11);
#endregion
}
```

#### Tested method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost, ParameterBasedOnFormName("save-continue", "continueEditing")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel model, bool continueEditing, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var schedules = await _shippingApiClient.GetAllFixedSchedules(cancellationToken);
    if (schedules.Any(s => s.Name.Equals(model.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Name), _localizationService.GetResource("Bizay.Logistic.Admin.Schedules.Error.Name.Repeated"));
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _shippingApiClient.CreateFixedSchedule(new FixedShippingScheduleEditModel { Name = model.Name }, cancellationToken);

        var refreshedSchedules = await _shippingApiClient.GetAllFixedSchedules(cancellationToken);
        var schedule = refreshedSchedules?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == model.Name);

        if (schedule == null)
        {
            _notificationService.ErrorNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Bizay.Logistic.Admin.Schedules.Notification.Create.Error"));
            return View(model);
        }
        _notificationService.SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Bizay.Logistic.Admin.Schedules.Notification.Create.Success"));
        if (continueEditing)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = schedule.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

What happens here is that `schedules.Any(s => s.Name.Equals(model.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))` should be working on the `schedules` list whereas the `refreshedSchedules?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == model.Name)` should be working on the `refreshedSchedules` list, the problem is that is that both lambdas are acting on the `schedules` list, any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: Your [MCVE] missing `ToIList` method...

Comment: Try using It.Is<...>(...) inside Setup for GetAllFixedSchedules.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `public IList<T> ToIList<T>(List<T> t) { return t; }`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I replaced `ToIlist` with a cast.

Comment: @anastaciu I also hope you understand what I was referring to about providing the necessary context information for us to be able to better provide you with an answer. Happy coding.

Comment: @Nkosi, no problem, I wasn't quite sure how to provide the necessary code, so I tried to simplify it, I thought it would be better, apparently no ;) I will try the provided solution and give the appropriate feedback, thank you for your help.

Comment: I've been there myself. Sometimes in our quest to simplify things, it removes too much context. Finding that balance comes with practice.

Comment: @Nkosi and I forgot to change the assertions, those were for a View return, I see fixed that too, thanks again for the great work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `_shippingApiClient` is a Moq `Mock<ShippingApiClient>`, you want to set up a `Callback` that populates a list that later calls to `GetAllFixedSchedules()` will fulfill:

```
//Arrnge
int id = 10;
string expectedName = "Schedule";
var viewModel = new FixedShippingScheduleEditViewModel { Name = expectedName };
var scheduleList = new List<Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel>() 
{ 
    new Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel { Id = id++, Name = "AnotherSchedule" } //Id = 10
};

_shippingApiClient
    .Setup(x => x.CreateFixedSchedule(It.IsAny<FixedShippingScheduleEditModel>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Callback((FixedShippingScheduleEditModel model, CancellationToken token) => {
        // TODO: perhaps some asserts here
        model.Id = id; //Since id is being asserted
        scheduleList.Add(new Hyper360FixedShippingScheduleSummaryModel
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name
        });
    })
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

_shippingApiClient
    .Setup(x => x.GetAllFixedSchedules(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => scheduleList);

//...code omitted for brevity

//Act
var result = await _scheduleController.Create(viewModel, true, CancellationToken.None);


//Assert
result.Should().BeOfType<RedirectToActionResult>();
RedirectToActionResult redirect = (RedirectToActionResult) result;
redirect.ActionName.Should().Be("Edit");
redirect.RouteValues["id"].Should().Be(id);
```

With callbacks, you can set up a mock with some sort of (locally kept) state.

Alternatively, set up sequential calls, see [Different return values the first and second time with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287540/different-return-values-the-first-and-second-time-with-moq), where you first return the initial list, then the list with the added item, but that is brittle - if you add another call in between, results will be off.