# How to mock a method that is called multiple times in single call using Moq in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, moq-3

I am trying to **mock** the below method but the **updateRefundReqeust** returns **null** instead updated record.

```
public async Task<bool> InvokeAsync(Batch batch)
{
        var refundRequests = await this.RefundRequestRepository.GetsAsync(batch.RefundRequests.Select(x => x.Id));

        foreach (var getRefundRequest in refundRequests)
        {
            getRefundRequest.Status = RefundRequestStatus.Closed;
            getRefundRequest.LastUpdatedBy = "Test User";

            RefundRequest updateRefundReqeust = await UpdateRefund.InvokeAsync(getRefundRequest);
           //Returns null instead of updated record
        }
}
```

**Unit test and Mocking** method

```
[Fact]
public async Task Post_Batch()
{
    var refundRequests = await this.RefundRequestRepository.GetsAsync(batch.RefundRequests.Select(x => x.Id));

    foreach (var getRefundRequest in refundRequests)
    {
        this.MockUpdateRefund
        .Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(getRefundRequest))
        .Returns(async () =>
        {
            getRefundRequest.Status = RefundRequestStatus.Closed;
            getRefundRequest.LastUpdatedBy = Factory.RefundRequest.TestUserName;
            return await Task.Run(() => getRefundRequest);
        });
    }

    var postRefund = await PostBatch.InvokeAsync(batch);

    //Assert
    postRefund.ShouldNotBeNull();
    postRefund.IsPosted.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

Is something missed in the Mocking? Please let me know if more stuffs are required to support the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of points:

- You don't need to setup a Mock multiple times, if all the Mocked calls are to return the same value. One Setup will service all calls with the given result.
- If you want the mocked dependency to return different canned values on each call, then use [SetupSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294711) and then chain as many `Returns` / `ReturnsAsync` for each result. However, it looks like you need to intercept the parameter and mutate it, and return it - there are `Returns` overloads which capture the parameter.
- For async methods, you'll want to use [ReturnsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117378) instead of `Returns`. Both of these have overloads allowing you to capture the passed parameter to the mocked method.
- You probably don't want the overhead of a new thread with `Task.Run`. `Task.FromResult` will return you a task wrapping the result.
- You typically won't want to Setup on a reference type unless you know for sure that the same reference instance will be passed to the dependency, since if any other instance is passed, the Mock will be ignored. `It.Is/IsAny` can be used as wildcards.

I believe you want something along the lines of:

```
this.MockUpdateRefund
    .Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<RefundRequest>()))
    .ReturnsAsync<RefundRequest>((RefundRequest getRefundRequest) =>
    {
        getRefundRequest.Status = RefundRequestStatus.Closed;
        getRefundRequest.LastUpdatedBy = Factory.RefundRequest.TestUserName;
        return Task.FromResult(getRefundRequest);
    });
```